# How can I remove duplicate masks from segment-anything?

Tags: python, duplicates, image-segmentation

I have a `microscobic` image dataset and I want to segment each texture of that image. I have used segment-anything model to segment these textures and strictly speaking it provides very good results for my dataset.

But in detail review I found there are some duplicate masks. I want to remove this duplicates. I go through the `automatic_mask_generator.p`y and tried to fine tune the value `crop_nms_thresh`. But it did not work. How can I remove these duplicates?

My image that I want to segment:

[image: My image that I want to segment]

segmentation outputs that contains duplicates is shown below:

Correct segmentation:

[image: correct segmentation]

Duplicate segmentation:

[image: duplicate segmentation]

How can I remove duplicate masks from segment anything outputs?

Comment: if you have similar images then if you subtract images then most pixels should reduce to  zero. If you sum all pixels then you should get almost zero - you would need to use some small value instead of zero as `threshold`. WIth `Black&White` images as `numpy arrays` it could looks similar to `sum(image1 - image2) < threshold`